# Terminal and caffeine-indicator

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Do I just type in caffeine-indicator just like that in the terminal? I have already put the command for caffeine in the terminal and it went through O.K. It just won't show up anywhere so I can click on it to start it and I did reboot. So just type in caffeine-indicator in the terminal just like what I typed just now?

Answer (score 5):

To add the PPA, open terminal from the Dash or by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T. When it opens, run command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
```

After that, update package cache and install the indicator by running below two commands one by one:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

Now to run the caffeine indicator from terminal easily open your terminal and run the command:

```
caffeine
```

Note that whenever you start a command by first letters then use the tricky double <kbd>tab</kbd> key to autocomplete or show all commands starting with those letters.

Answer (score 2):

New versions of Caffeine don't show up anywhere. They work in background and disable screensaver, when full-screen video is displayed. If you need that old cup for manual toggle, you can install caffeine-plus.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine-plus
```

Comment: caffeine-indicator does exactly that as of Ubuntu 19.10.